# Can't open jsp in WEB-INF subfolder using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to open the jsp pages of my application but I get error. Here is my project structure

```
-webapp
  -WEB-INF
    -pages
      -user
         userHome.jsp
         userAdministration.jsp
      index.jsp
```

Here is my configuration class

```
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
...
```

***Index.jsp is my start page.***

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<a href="<c:url value="/user" />" role="button">User</a>
```

**userHome.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    ...
<a href="<c:url value="/user/administration" />">Administration</a>
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    ...
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userArea(Model model) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("user/userHome");
    mv.addObject("title", "Home Page");
    return mv;
}
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/administration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView administration(Model model) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("user/userAdministration");
        mv.addObject("title", "Administration");
        return mv;
    }
...
```

userHome page opens correctly, but when I click the link to move to userAdministration I get the following error

[image]

Help me please open this page.

Comment: Try `resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");`, note slash at the beginning of `WEB-INF`

Comment: @Arvind, it worked! Post the answer, please, and I'll accept it! Thank you so much, I've had to struggle a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are missing `/` in the beginning:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
```